# Extends constructor

Tags: magento2, extend, construct

I have a class that extends `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info` and I want to extend its constructor to get customer session, but how do I extend constructor?

PhpStorm is highlighting my constructor I don't know why (the same constructor than a "regular" constructor of one of my custom block)

Comment: why you need  customer session?

Comment: Because I need customer data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class constructor can be extended like any other PHP class constructor, just make sure to pass the same parameters that the extended `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info` class is using.

In your case the `Info.php` constructor looks something like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $helperView,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
    $this->_subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    $this->_helperView = $helperView;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

So your class should look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard;

class InfoExtended extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $helperView,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        // Your new properties here
        parent::__construct($context, $currentCustomer, $subscriberFactory, $helperView, $data);
    }
}
```

BTW, the class you're extending already exposes the current customer session as `$currentCustomer` property so you can probably use that without overriding the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

As @JavierVillanueva suggested in his answer, you don't need to define a constructor in your class, if it extends the class `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info`.

You will get the customer instance by the call: `$this->getCustomer()` in your custom class.

Comment: Yes you're right !